# How do I remove an image completely from a posted question?

Tags: support, privacy

I have posted a question "How do I use serialEvent() in a Processing language program?" and originally included an image, not realising immediately that it contains the precise GPS co-ordinates of my house. I remove the image by editing, but, of course it is still there for anyone to see who examines the editing. Please, as a matter of urgency, can the image be completely removed?, or the co-ordinates blocked out?

Comment: Whatever you do, *don't* post a question on Meta so that everyone who sees it will find your house ..... oh, too late ....

Comment: Folishly I panicked

Comment: It's not so bad, I've seen someone posted his username and password into a question and edit to remove it then...okay let's all panic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply delete the image and flag the post for moderator attention. We can now redact revisions without bothering the community managers, so this will get processed as soon as a moderator sees the flag. A second moderator has to approve the redaction (to guard against mistakes being made), but the process is usually fairly quick.

<s>Either use the Contact Us form to speak directly to the community managers or flag the post for moderator attention using the "other" option explaining that you'd like the old revisions of the post expunged from the database. In the latter case all we can do is pass the request along to the community managers - as they're the only ones who can do this.</s>

In the meantime if you're really worried about people seeing the history delete the post and we'll restore it once the revisions have gone.

As to removing the image - I don't know if you can do that. You'd have to contact the team via the "contact us" form and ask them if they can remove the image. Include the url of the image on imgur so they know which one you want deleting.

Comment: where do I get updates about the question I flagged? I had flagged a question, and nothing seemed to change.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "contact us" link in the footer to write to SE and ask them to remove the information. They are the only ones with the ability to do that.

You could also flag the post, but then a moderator would simply forward that request to an SE employee anyway.